# JQuery append to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the following html:

```
<div class="section grouping">
    <div class="sectionControl">
        <div class="parent row errorOn">
            <div class="validGroupControl">
                <div class="row2 itemWrap clearfix">
                    <label>Login1 (adress e-mail)<span class="iconReq">&nbsp;</span>:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text">
                </div>
                <div class="itemWrap clearfix">
                    <label>Input field1<span class="iconReq">&nbsp;</span>:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="text">
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="iconClose" onclick="$(this).closest('div.parent').remove();" title="remove">remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row addControl">
        <a href="#" class="button" onclick="$('div.sectionControl').append($('div.sectionControl div.parent:last').html());">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to do the following:
clicking "add" button would take `<div class="parent...">` and append it to `<div class="sectionControl">`

Pretty much i want it so that when i click Add button new `<div class="parent"` will be added underneath previous `<div class="parent...">` and right above:

```
                     </div>
                     <div class="row addControl">
```

when i try it with the parent() like so:

```
alert($('div.sectionControl div.parent:last').parent().html())
```

i get duplicates. so instead of adding just one i get original + what i just added. I'm not sure how to handle this.

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, take that inline `onclick` code out and attach using jQuery:

```
$('div.addControl a.button').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.section.grouping').find('.parent:last');
    parent.after(parent.clone());
});
```

Note the `'.parent:last'`, which will select only *one* of the divs.

Comment: is there a way to check if there's only 1 in a group?. i want to be able to remove that "REMOVE" button if there's only 1 (div.parent) in the sectionControl group. thanks

Comment: @Shane, I'm not sure what you want to do, but to check if there's only one `.parent` then you can use: `$(this).closest('.section.grouping').find('.parent').length == 1`